PIxels drawn every other pixel
Like the title, I have a program drawing some cubes on screen, the problem appeared after I switched computers, from desktop to laptop (Which has a bigger resolution).
I'm using the half space algorthim to fill the triangles on the cubes, as such:
DIMENSION tr = new DIMENSION(tri.outline.x, tri.outline.y, tri.outline.w, tri.outline.h);
for(int x = tr.x; x < tr.w; x++){
    for(int y = tr.y; y < tr.h; y++){
        double ha = FNS.HalfSpace(a, b, x, y); // for A and B points
        double hb = FNS.HalfSpace(b, c, x, y); // for B and C points
        double hc = FNS.HalfSpace(c, a, x, y); // for C and A points
        if(ha > 0 && hb > 0 && hc > 0) g.drawRect(x, y, 0, 0);
    }   
}

Which looks like:

I tried changing the width and height of the drawn rectangle to 1, which certainly then filled the cubes, but showed alot of artifacts and misplaced pixels.
The only difference is, that i'm on my laptop instead of desktop, on desktop all worked perfectly fine.
